# Converting to datetime in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am having trouble with converting a datetime string to a datetime object (for plotting)

```
#The Date (as date[1]):
"9/1/2015 1:08AM"

#The Command:
as.POSIXlt(date[1], "%m/%d/%y %I:%M%p")

#The Result:
"9-01-20"

#Desired Result:
"9-01-2015 1:20"
```

Comment: You are also parsing your format into the `tz` variable, try `as.POSIXlt(date[1], format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p")`. Your desired output doesn't make much sense neither. Why would `1:08AM` should become `1:20`?

Comment: Really, I dont care about how the exact output is.  I just need something that R can parse and then plot (as the x axis to my data)

Comment: David, if you make that an answer, I'll mark it as correct, as it solves my problem.  What was my issue, that I didn't specify the "format = "?  I did read it, I just assumed 1:20 would convert into 24 hour time, thus losing the %p (as that's more standard)

Comment: Yes, if you'll look into `?as.POSIXlt` you'll see that `tz` comes before `format`. You also (like was mentioned by Richard) used `y` instead of `Y`.

Comment: I would suggest checking out the `lubridate` package. It is very easy to work with (and good to learn).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into lubridate for the future :D